# What's the right/best way to handle nullable parameters in Insight.Database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, insight.database

I've been using [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) for about a year to invoke stored procedures, but I've only just run into a situation where the stored procedure has a defaultable nullable parameter that Insight doesn't handle as I was expecting.

Briefly, the parameter is defined as `paramName nvarchar(10) = ''`. The code to invoke this proc was old fashioned SqlCommand/SqlParam code that simply did not set the param at all. I was replacing this with a .net object:

```
Class MyObject
    Public Property paramName As String
    ....
End Class
```

Suppose you create an object of this type, do NOT set `paramName` and pass it to the proc. I would have expected that the proc would use the default value. But what happens instead is that Insight sends a NULL value to the proc, which is NOT the same as not sending anything, the proc sees a specified parameter and so doesn't use the default value, and this particular proc actually handled NULL is a *different* way from the default, which broke the app.

I would argue that the bug is in the proc, but I still need a way to control nullable parameter behavior so I can call procs of this kind that I can't modify.

Comment: This one is not working ? CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.abc
(
 @Parm1 VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)

Comment: I'm sure it would work, but that isn't how this proc is defined. I need to call the proc as is, and can't change it to make it easier for me to call.

Comment: Ok Sorry, I am going to remove my answer

Comment: please explain me with example if you have time

Comment: I thought I did in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy that you've had a year of success with Insight.Database.

When Insight binds an object to a parameter list, it maps any properties that match.

So:

```
class Foo { string Param; }
CREATE PROC MyProc (@Param varchar(50))
```

Foo.Param maps to @Param

In MOST simple cases, coders want NULL to map to DBNull.Value. So if Param is NULL, Insight will bind the parameter and set @Param to (DB)NULL.

When you use ADO.NET to call a stored proc with a default parameter, you usually omit the parameter or don't set the value. ADO.NET then tells the server to use the default.

```
CREATE PROC MyProc (@Param varchar(50) = NULL)
```

You can do this with Insight by omitting the parameter entirely:

```
class Foo { /* Param not bound */ }
```

Insight then leaves the value unbound and ADO.NET will use the default.

I haven't run across a case where you have to use both a default parameter AND NULL values on the same proc.

So the simplest solution is to omit the parameter, but if that doesn't work, I can probably add a feature that lets you control what NULL means. Like:

```
class Foo { [NullMeansUseDefault] string Param; }
```

Of course, I'd want a better name for the attribute.

If you think the feature would solve your problem, please open an issue over at  https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/issues

Comment: I'm happy too, because it's a great library that has saved me a ton of work. I don't think the problem is that the proc uses "both a default parameter AND NULL values", it's that the proc doesn't expect null at all. The param has a default value (the empty string ''), and has code in it like `if @paramName = ''`. Because Insight is passing NULL, this fails. I think this would be an issue any time a proc has a default value that isn't NULL, and the calling code can't simply omit the parameter--in this case, because sometimes you DO want to specify it.

Comment: Does Insight work in this way because it has no knowledge of the proc *other* than the properties, and so it has to assume you want to pass them all, because it doesn't know what params have defaults?

Comment: It knows the types and which ones have defaults, but I'm not sure that I would change the meaning of null to default.

Comment: I added issue #157 to track this: https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/issues/157

Comment: Thanks. That issue captures it well, and I'll look into the workaround, and comment there.